# Insert Array of Structs into DB using gorm

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I need to insert into a Postgresql database using `gorm`. But the struct in question has fields containing arrays of custom types:

```
type VideoFile struct {
    UID      string
    FileName string
    Format   string
    Path     string
}


type myStruct struct {
    ID                string
    UserId            uint64
    UserType          int
    FaceVideoFiles    []VideoFile
    MeetingVideoFiles []VideoFile
}

func (r *videoRepo) CreateRecord(input *myStruct) error {
    tx := r.base.GetDB().Begin()
    err := tx.Create(input).Error
    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return err
    }
    tx.Commit()
    return nil
}
```

ID field is the primary key in database. I am not sure which tags to add to the struct fields so I leave it empty here (e.g. `gorm:"primaryKey" json:"id"`, etc). If the `FaceVideoFiles` is not an array of struct, things seem to work, but that is not the case with an array of struct. What should I do so that I can insert those *arrays of structs* (not individual structs) into my database?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use one to many. More information related to this. Please follow documentation. https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html#Has-Many

```
type Dog struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
  Toys []Toy `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;"`
}

type Toy struct {
  ID        int
  Name      string
  OwnerID   int
  OwnerType string
}

db.Create(&Dog{Name: "dog1", Toys: []Toy{{Name: "toy1"}, {Name: "toy2"}}})
// INSERT INTO `dogs` (`name`) VALUES ("dog1")
// INSERT INTO `toys` (`name`,`owner_id`,`owner_type`) VALUES ("toy1","1","dogs"), ("toy2","1","dogs")
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, but `myStruct` is also the model for my database table, the only single at the moment. From your reply, I suppose I have to make other separate table(s) to house record about individual videos, then draw a one-to-many relationship with my current single table?